# Issue with java paint on frame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, paint

I am creating an object of another class from my main class using the following call:

```
JSplash splash = new JSplash();
```

However, when I create this object it performs the constructor of the JSplash class and gives my window and my button. But it does not paint on the frame. Can you please assist me with this?

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

/**
 *
 * @author Curtis
 */
public class JSplash extends DFrame implements ActionListener {
//declaration of variable objects
    Font myFont = new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 20);
    JButton myButton = new JButton("Click Me!");
    Color bgColor = new Color(0, 0, 255);
    Color firstColor = new Color(255, 255, 255);
    String first = "Welcome to DaemoDynamics!";
    String last = "Click the Button";
    String middle = "";
    String middle2 = "";
    private static int count = 1;
    DFrame splash = new DFrame();
//Constructor
    public JSplash() {
        setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
        System.out.println("Hello");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
        splash.add(myButton);
        getContentPane().setBackground(bgColor);
        //adds action listener
        myButton.addActionListener(this);
        splash.setVisible(true);
    }
//Paint method
    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics e) {
        System.out.println("paint is being reached");
        super.paint(e);
        e.setFont(myFont);
        e.setColor(firstColor);
        e.drawString(first, 14, 80);
        e.drawString(last, 70, 240);
        e.drawString(middle, 75, 150);
        e.drawString(middle2, 60, 175);
    }

//Listener Method
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        //First Time button hit
        if (count == 1) {
            middle = "Brighter Business";
            middle2 = "for A Brighter Future";
            last = "Click Again to Begin";
            repaint();
            //increases button count
            count++;
        } else//if button count is not 1
        {
            splash.setVisible(false);
            FinalProject app = new FinalProject();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry for the paint is being reached line I was trying to see that method was getting any action at all....its not

Comment: added `splash.setLayout(new BorderLayout());`  and then changed to `add(myButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);`   No effect

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: You've create a NEW `DFrame` inside you `JSplash` constructor and then ADDED your components to IT. This is simply not required.  Remove the reference's to splash and simply use the `DFrame` you've extended.  And while i'm looking at, splash has no layout manager, which isn't going to help.  The `paint` method is never going to be called, because the window that's displayed on the screen is never the `JSplash`, but the `DFrame` you created (called splash)

Comment: Its odd I finally figured this out for myself after an hour of confusion and came to edit this post.  thank you for confirming my issue

Comment: Well, depending on what answer best meet your needs, choose as accepeted...I moved my comment down to an answer, but if Vamsi's answer helped more, please feel free to select his.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've create a NEW `DFrame` inside you `JSplash` constructor and then ADDED your components to IT. This is simply not required. Remove the reference's to splash and simply use the `DFrame` you've extended. And while i'm looking at, splash has no layout manager, which isn't going to help. The paint method is never going to be called, because the window that's displayed on the screen is never the `JSplash`, but the `DFrame` you created (called splash)

Answer (score 0):

Create a new class that extends JPanel. Ensure your button is added to that panel and override the paintComponent() method of that panel with your logic. This should work.

[Refer here.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/step2.html)

Custom painting should be done in paintComponent method. Ideally you should not override the paint method of a JFrame.